# Start game when user press 'n' key

Tags: jquery

I want to show a text when user press `n` button.

For example show `You pressed n button`

My language is javascript and I use jQuery too.

Before I wrote this question, I tested this code:

```
$(window).keypress(function (event) {
   if(event.which==78){
       console.log('true')
   }
})
```

Thank guys;

Comment: what's the error you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

It's enough to change from:

```
if(event.which==78){
```

to:

```
if(String.fromCharCode(event.which)=='n'){
```

```js
$(window).keypress(function (event) {
    if(String.fromCharCode(event.which)=='n'){
        console.log('true')
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the `Enter` button?
or `shift` or `Ctrl` 
or multi key for example `Ctrl + shift`
also `arrow keys`